# What do "!" and "." mean in BASIC?

Tags: basic, legacy

Trying to translate BASIC code written in the 1990's to Python. I keep coming across two symbols, `!` (exclamation mark) and `.` (period). I can't find any documentation online on what they do.
I have the code running but some of the outputs are not as expected - I am wondering if these might be the issue as I previously thought that the period may just be a typo for a multiplication.

Examples:

```
                                                          |
                                                          v
QWLOST = (((TW-TDAO)/(TWRT-TDAOR))^1.25)*((VISR/VIS)^0.25).(PW+PE)*DT

TFAVE = (TTO+TBO)/2!
                   ^
                   |
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else in the future needs to know this.

! - defines a single
. - Was just a typo for * (multiplication)

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few things in bwBasic (in Linux, in case that's relevant!).

```
bwBASIC: list
10: for i = 1 to 20
20:   print i, ., . - i
30: next i
40: print ".="; .
```

This gave me:

> ```
> bwBASIC: run
>  1            20            19
>  2            20            18
>  3            20            17
>  4            20            16
>  5            20            15
>  6            20            14
>  7            20            13
>  8            20            12
>  9            20            11
>  10           20            10
>  11           20            9
>  12           20            8
>  13           20            7
>  14           20            6
>  15           20            5
>  16           20            4
>  17           20            3
>  18           20            2
>  19           20            1
>  20           20            0
> .= 20
> ```

Which would suggest that `.` (in bwBasic in any case) is the max number in a `for` loop.

Comment: I think that's quite special to the BASIC dialect.  In most if not all classic Microsoft based dialects the . is a way to express the number 0.0 because both leading and trailing digits are optional for floating point literals in those dialects.  Somewhat widely known tidbit, because that was a common tip for optimizing for speed, because . was processed faster than 0 by the interpreter.